# Why can't i diffrentate by taking logarithms directly?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I came across a question:

If $y^x + x^y + x^x = a^b,$ find $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

The question itself is relatively straightforward, the problem is that my answer isn't the same as the book's.

I proceeded by taking logarithms of both sides and then differentiating them i.e

$x\log y + y\log x + x\log x = b\log a$

However my book does it like this:

let $u = x\log y $
    $v = y\log x$
    $k = x \log x$

And then differentiates them, substituting their product in the equation. Both methods yield different answers.

My question is, why is it incorrect to just directly take the logarithm followed by differentiation than to substitute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT:**

$\log(a+b)\ne \log a + \log b$

So,

$\log(y^x+x^y+x^x) \ne \log x^x + \log x^y + \log x^x$

Comment: I can't believe i did that.. thank you!

Comment: @mathman123 happens to the best of us ;p